# Unit Testing Assertion of Browser Creation

Tags: c#, unit-testing, assertions

I am trying to write an automated test that will check that a new browser was not created when a link is clicked. A tab is opened instead. But I am not sure how I would assert that.

```
this.TestContext.WriteLine("Step 3: Click the View Now button in the video List.");
browser.MainPage.TrainingContent.OnDemandTab.ClickVideoLink(Guid.NewGuid());
this.TestContext.WriteLine("Assert: Verify new tab is created.");
Assert.IsTrue(browser.MainPage.TrainingContent.OnDemandTab.CurrentVideo());
browser.MainPage.TrainingContent.OnDemandTab.VideoWindow.Close();

this.TestContext.WriteLine("Step 4: Click the View Now button in the video  List.");
browser.MainPage.TrainingContent.OnDemandTab.ClickVideoLink(Guid.NewGuid());
this.TestContext.WriteLine("Assert: Verify new tab is created.");
Assert.IsFalse(browser.MainPage.TrainingContent.OnDemandTab.CurrentVideo());
browser.MainPage.TrainingContent.OnDemandTab.VideoWindow.Close();
```

In order to accomplish this I was thinking of trying to assert that another browser was not created (another window). But I am not sure how to set it up.

Comment: I don't understand the context of this question at all. Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: This is a coded UI test that is opening a video link on a certain page in this application. The link is supposed to create a new browser tab when accessed. Not open another window instead.

Comment: This is not unit test.